# Oracle APEX - how to make an Interactive Grid column (display only) into a multi-line

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive grid column Display only and I want to make it into multi-line. is that possible? How can I make the text wrap? Changing column width does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Apex itself doesn't support such a thing - not in a declarative way. Just like an Interactive or a Classic Report, Interactive Grid (as well as former Tabular Form) present everything in a long, single line.

What you want would be possible in, for example, Oracle Forms, which allow you to display a single line of data in several rows, but - in Forms - you can actually *drag and drop* items wherever you want. Apex can't do that.

On the other hand, maybe there is a way to do that using some other techniques, additional programming and stuff, but I don't know anything about it.